# receiving runtime error on docker container only for specific machine

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, tomcat8, docker-for-mac

I have a 3rd party java webapp that runs within apache Tomcat. We are using docker to run this application. When run on my machine, we receive an error

I want to stress that we do not build this `.war`. We do not own this `.war`. We are simply trying to spin up a docker container that runs this already built code.

`javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)`

with the details

`java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status does not implement the requested interface javax.ws.rs.core.Response$StatusType`

investigating this online a bit shows a lot of people having issues with conflicting jersey jars. We should not have that problem because we using docker for mac... and this works on everyone else's machine across multiple version of docker.

I have wiped out and reinstalled docker multiple times, restarting my machine inbetween each restart. I have used the same version as machines where it does work.

I am on OSX Sierra 10.12.2

The docker image is based on `tomcat:8.5.9-jre8-alpine`
It copies the relevant `.war` to `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/` and a single log4j `.jar` to `$CATALINA_HOME/lib/` along with a two .properties files.'

is there anything on this specific machine that could possible be interfering with the container?

Dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.9-jre8-alpine@sha256:780c0fc47cf5e212bfa79a379395444a36bbd67f0f3cd9d649b90a74a1a7be20

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m"

WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME

COPY ./target/lib/* $CATALINA_HOME/lib/
COPY ./target/<appname>.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Comment: Are you using the same binary war everywhere shared from a common repo, such as nexus? If you're rebuilding it on each environment then the problem lies in your build system for the war, not in docker or tomcat.

Comment: we have committed the .war to git and in the build step of the container just copy it to the the webapps directory

Comment: Please show us your Dockerfile (suitably redacted of course)

Comment: And you are all using a common image too? Not rebuilding it all locally for each machine?

Comment: building the image locally, though a coworker published his built image and i got the same result

Comment: @EngineerDollery please see edited question with dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Check all the volumes, most critical ones in that case are mounts from your ~/.m2 into the container ~/.m2 .. this would explain your issue.

Other then that, it would not make sense, that it works on one machine, and not the other, as long as you use the same image AND:

a) The compilation of the WAR file does not happen on the probelematic computer ( most probably local a maven / m2 ) issue then

b) You do not do any crazy stuff in the entrypoint really hurting the paradigm ( i do no think so )

c) You mount your local m2 into the containers m2 and thus share libs

We do run a lot of tomcat containers with different war apps and they, as you expect, run absolutely cross platform.

Hint: To avoid a) *always* build in the image using the image java env.

Comment: If this is a standard war, then the runtime container should have neither maven nor .m2, and there should be no external dependencies other than the standard environment provided ones such as logger (and even that is a push).

Comment: It depends how the war-file is bundled,obviously - how many libs are used from the actual tomcat container, like mysql-connector and things, while the war file might have been compiled against a different interface `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status does not implement the requested interface javax.ws.rs.core.Response$StatusType` - this error is *exactly* what you get with wrong-version runtime-dependency of a war file

Comment: the maven and .m2 bits of my comment are not dependant on the way the war file is bundled. As for container-provided dependencies -- the dependency mismatch problem is why it's bad practice to depend on environment provided libs. See 12FA (https://12factor.net/)

Comment: i do not argue, but the question is, why it happens and i guess that is the answer for it :) Your suggestion is perfectly right and also my hint would not fix it all, when you use runtime dependencies int he pom file. It has its usecases in frameworks, but they are very rare (OSGi related)